# Error while using npm run dev command to run a next js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, deployment

error in the terminal:

```
$ npm run dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HARSH KUMAR\Desktop\Amazon watchdog\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HARSH KUMAR\Desktop\Amazon watchdog\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HARSH KUMAR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-29T03_32_33_232Z-debug-0.log
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

How can i resolve this error , I've tried updating , node , npm but i'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run in the correct directory containing the package.json file